# How to create conditional xpath in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

My `HTML` code looks like:

Table 1: And Table 2

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder_Body0">
    <tbody>
        <tr align="Center">
            <td style="width:250px;">Some Name</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder_Body1">
    <tbody>
        <tr align="Center">
            <td style="width:250px;">Some Name</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I use `//*[contains(text(),'Some Name')]` this `xpath` selects 2 values while I need to select only one value by Text.
I need to use that `xpath` with Text.
I'm trying to create `xpath` to get the "Some Name" from Table 2, element locator by using Text.
So I created this `Xpath`:

```
//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder_Body1']//tr//td[@text()='Some Name']
```

This `xpath` is not working, need help to create correct `xpath`.

Comment: Can you share the page you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

Given your HTML, this XPath works for me

```
//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder_Body1']//td[text()='Some Name']
```

I think the issue with your XPath is that you were using `@text()` when it should be `text()`.

```
//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder_Body1']//tr//td[@text()='Some Name']
                                                ^ remove the @
```

Comment: Thank you very much its work for me as well

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just remove the `@`

```
//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder_Body1']//tr//td[text()='Some Name']
```

Comment: Thank you very much its work for me as well